# Angularjs - promise not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

im working with angular.js and I need promises now. I have used it before, but at the moment, I'm not able to make it work.

After I create the product, I need to get the `id` for using it later and add more stuffs with this `id`. So I need to wait for the create product process and after it, do what I want. But after 3 days trying, I decided to ask for help.

That's my code:

```
var product = new Product($scope.product);
product.supplierId = $scope.supplierId;
product.status = 'empty';
product.idParent = parentId;
console.log(product);
product.$save(function (data) {
  ['buyer', 'seller'].forEach(function (role) {
    var notification = new Notification({
      role: role,
      subject: 'Se ha creado un nuevo producto.',
      productId: data.id,
      productDescription:  $scope.currentUser.supplier.name
    });
    notification.$save();
  });
  ngNotify.set('Producto creado exitosamente.', 'success');
  $location.path('/catalogo/productos/' + data.id);
});
```

*I removed some code for easy reading, maybe I'm missing a semicolon or something. But it works.*

I've tried to get it using promises (q and bluebird) but I'm missing something and I dont know how to get the `id` for using it later in `.then()` function.

How can I do it using promises? I have q and bluebird promises, I may use one of them.

**Solved!**

Just add this (remove semicolon) :

```
.then(function (data) {
    //Here you have data.id
});
```

Regards!

Comment: Check if can get id by using ``role.id`` instead of ``data.id`` ? and where is the code for ''then`` ??

Comment: HI @SameerK , I tried many times use `then()` but it's removed from the code, you are watching original code without promises.

Comment: Whether data is saving ??  for your info this is syntax to capture promise. ``product.save().then(function (data) {
   //rest code here
}, function (err) {
    self.err = err.message;
});``

Comment: I solved it. But I dont know why I dont need to set up promises. I mean after all the code (after `save` function) just included a `.then()` and it works.

Why I dont need to use `$promise.then()` or similars in somewhere of my code? I mean, just using `.then` with no set up?

Comment: that's because internally .$save() already returns a promise. That should be your cue really, when you perform the deferred action, then.... Kinda makes sense when you think about it

Comment: Yes, I thought it. That make me love angular much more. Thx guys.